# Create own screen resolution without Nvidia

Tags: unity, drivers, multiple-monitors

I had a problem with my monitor Dell E207WFP. The first time I connected it to my Ubuntu, it had a possibility to set 1600x1040 resolution, but then I reinstalled some drivers and use set default settings option in monitor, now it has only a 1024x768 available resolution.

I read a tutorial on how to make this with Nvidia driver, but Nvidia made me lots of another troubles and I don't want it on my Ubuntu.

Comment: It is funny, i used another connection wire and now my Ubuntu see not unknown monitor but Dell20", funny because this wire is older and malfunctioning cable was purchased yesterday because of the length of it (I needed longerer) The connector is VGA.

Mabye this post will help somebody.